# Ввод в консольное приложение

Tags: c++, windows

Система Windows. Имеется консольное приложение "А" на C++, которое вызывает другое консольное приложение "Б". Программа "А" должна ввести строковые данные в консоль приложения "Б". Как это сделать?

Comment: Эээ... А что по вашему есть «консоль приложения "Б"»? У консольного приложения нету _собственной_ консоли, оно _запускается_ в консоли, так что у обоих приложений будет _общая_ консоль.

Comment: Опишите точнее, какого эффекта вы хотите добиться.

Answer (score 3):

Выполните в консоли:

```
a.exe | b.exe
```

Текст на выходе из приложения A будет перенаправлен на вход приложению B.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте системные функции [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) и CreatePipe.
Структура _STARTUPINFO, указатель на которую передается в функцию CreateProcess, содержит хэндл hStdInput, который нужно подменить.

Вот пример:
http://www.sources.ru/cpp/using_anonymous_pipes.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Можно вызвать приложение B, передав ему строковые данные параметром. Для этого в приложении B `main` должен выглядеть так:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string str = argv[1]; /*именно первый, а не нулевой аргумент*/
```

а как вызвать приложение B - написал Athari